# IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE problems

Tags: php, png, gd, transparent, colorize

I already got some great advice on the forums how to get the colorize function using imagefilter IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE.

The problem is that it doesn't work as I want it to work, the link below illustrates it best:
http://expromo.pl/klienci/imagefilter/

I have a transparent png containing some kind of shape.
I want to:

- Change the color of the shape just as Photoshop Layer Settings /
  Colorize would
- Preserve the transparency
- Save it as another PNG file

Here is my code:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');
imagealphablending($im, false);

if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0,0,255,0))
{
    imagepng($im, 'image-new.png');
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

On the link above:
http://expromo.pl/klienci/imagefilter/

The first image is what I have. The second image is what I get, and the third image is what I want to get.

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You must add `imagesavealpha($im, true);` so the alpha channel will be saved on the new image.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');
imagealphablending($im, false);

imagesavealpha($im, true);

if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0,0,255,0)) {
    imagepng($im, 'image-new.png');
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Comment: How about semitransparent pixels? If you have 50% transparent black pixel and you want to fill it with 50% transparent blue, it becomes 50% black + 50% blue, how to make it entirely replace the color and calculate the new alpha, rather than mixing the colors?